# Setting Field Value in Customer Record after Invoice Creation

Tags: netsuite

In my customer record, I have a field called Membership Status. So the membership will change from Regular member to Prime member once a member purchase a particular item. Is there any way to update the field after the Invoice creation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use an `afterSubmit()` event on a `User Event` script deployed on the invoice record.  Search the invoice item lines for the item, and if found use [`record.submitFields(options)`](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45158) to update the field on the customer record.

If you are making other changes to the customer, you could use [`record.load(options)`](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45155) to load the whole record instead and then use the Record Object Methods to modify and save the record.

For updating a small number of body fields, `submitFields()` will usually be more performant, but if you need to manipulate sublists or subrecords, you need to load the record.

Comment: I wrote the script and it works perfectly fine when the invoice is created manually but it does not work when an Invoice is created from our POS system.

Comment: The reason for this will depend on how the invoices are brought into NetSuite from the POS system.  For example, if you run a csv import, by default it does not trigger server scripts, so the script would not run.